# Chrome/Safari Mobile - Images are being resized & compressed and look terrible

Tags: image, google-chrome, webkit, compression, mobile-safari

I am encountering an issue I have never seen before. During development of a new website, while testing on mobile I noticed my images are getting resized and compressed. An image that is normally 1600 by 600 naturally, is being resized and compressed to 375 by 140 this is then displayed as the natural size.

I have an older copy of the website with the same images. The issue does not occur with those.I have not implemented any server side caching yet.

Is anyone familiar with this issue? I haven't been able to find any information on it. I looked up 'Image compression bug on chrome', 'chrome resizing images', and at least a dozen other queries, but nothing that seemed to match my issue. Other colleagues are seeing the same issue on their own devices as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind. It turns out one of my colleagues in the past had run a small experiment with cookies and limiting the image widths, and had left it there.